# How to select a column from a subquery in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, rdbms

I am pretty new in sql.
i have this table.[image]

1st i want to select how many students are there in each course;

```
SELECT COURSE_ID,COUNT(COURSE_ID) AS C FROM STUDENT GROUP BY COURSE_ID
```

2ND now i want to select MAX(C) that is the highest value in count column from sub query.

SO

```
SELECT MAX(C) FROM (  SELECT COURSE_ID,COUNT(COURSE_ID) AS C FROM STUDENT GROUP BY COURSE_ID   );
```

output should be 3

IS THIS THE RIGHT WAY?
I AM USING MARIADB.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, does it yield the results you expect?

Comment: @ArSeN No, its not working.

Comment: when a subquery is used as a derived table (e.g. with FROM or JOIN), you need to give it an alias like `FROM (SELECT foo FROM bar) AS foo_bar;`

Comment: always important to say _how_ something is not working

Comment: @ysth thank you , after giviging the alias name i got the output.

Comment: If you don't want to use subquery, you can order your count descending and keep just the first record

Comment: @JaimeDrq having a sub query takes more time? is there any performence benefits of not using a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the subquery entirely by using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS C
FROM STUDENT
GROUP BY COURSE_ID
ORDER BY C DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The "LIMIT 1" only shows the first row after sorting it in decreasing order?

Comment: it would shoe you the max count as it is the first in that order